error updating objective c type information Apple TV app
I have Xamarin Apple TV app project which was running fine. Recently i updated Visual studio for mac to version 17.6.12 (build 410).
After the update, when i try to launch Main.storyboard using Xcode interface builder i am getting the following error.
    "ERROR [2024-06-05 22:16:40Z]: Error updating Objective-C type information
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MonoDevelop.MacDev.Utilities.TypeSystemServiceExtensions.GetRoslynCompilationAsync(IXcodeSyncableProject syncable) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/MonoDevelop.MacDev/MonoDevelop.MacDev/Utilities/TypeSystemServiceExtensions.cs:line 21
   at MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.NSObjectInfoService.GetProjectInfoAsync(IXcodeSyncableProject syncable) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/MonoDevelop.MacDev/MonoDevelop.MacDev/ObjCIntegration/NSObjectInfoService.cs:line 99
   at MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeProjectTracker.UpdateTypesAsync(ProgressMonitor monitor) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/MonoDevelop.MacDev/MonoDevelop.MacDev/XcodeSyncing/XcodeProjectTracker.cs:line 1169

How to solve this issue? Do i need to downgrade from the latest update?
